# Editing response content on doView()

Tags: java, portlet, jsr286, jsr168

I have a simple `JSR 286` Portlet that displays a user manual (pure `HTML` code, not `JSP`).

Actually, my `doView` method, just contains this :

```java
public class UserManualPortlet extends GenericPortlet
{

    @Override
    protected void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException
    {
        PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                "/html/usermanual.html");

        rd.include(request, response);    
    }
}
```

This works as expected, however I'm having trouble when including images. I'm aware that the path to images should be something like :

```java
<img src='<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/html/image.jpg")%>'/>
```

However, my HTML file containing the user manual is used elsewhere, so I would like to preserve it as a pure HTML file.

Is there a way to dynamically **replace** my classic `images urls` by something like the example above ? Perhaps using the `PrintWriter` of the response ?

If such thing is not possible, I thing I would need to generate a `JSP` file during my `Maven` build.

Any solution or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JSR-268 portlets you have a better way of referencing resources: create `ResourceURL` using `renderResponse.createResourceURL()` and then you set the `resourceID` in the `ResourceURL`. That should give more consistent results across all portlet containers.

That said, if you want to modify the generated content from your `usermanual.html` but you don't want to convert it to a JSP then, instead of using a request dispatcher, I would load the file contents on my own, parse it at the same time that I do the URL replacements and then print all the contents to the portlet's response.

Comment: Nice, but what do you mean by *loading on your own* ?

Comment: use `PortletContext.getRealPath("/html/usermanual.html")` to know the exact location of the file, then create a `BufferedReader` to load the contents, parse and make replacements, then write the results to either portlet's output stream or writer.